# Update lead time for one location based on item another location

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to set up a query for testing some software and need to adjust some data on the tables. In short, for all items that are located at factory A, then I want to update the lead times(int) for those items at all other factories to be equal to the lead time at factory A.

The end result I'm expecting would be for any item produced at factory A to have the same lead time no matter where it is located.

edit: Lets call the table "PRODUCTION"

Operation has "item", "location", and "leadtime" as fields.

What I've tried is to select a subquery of items at factory A and use that as a join back against the table to select the items.

```
select 
product,
location,
leadtime
from production join
(
    select product from production
    where location = 'F01'
) as a

on item = a.item

where location not like 'F01'
```

Comment: What Have You Tried(tm)? Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button below the tags and show us what attempt you've made at this, and include further information about the tables you're using, field names involved, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are getting the error message `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` because Oracle does not support `AS` for subquery aliases.  Also, it looks like `item = a.item` might lead to an ambiguous error message.

Since the product is optionally present in a different location, this sounds like a `LEFT JOIN`.  And `NVL` lets you use the other factory leadtime, if it exists, else use the existing leadtime.

Try this query:

```
select 
    production.product,
    production.location,
    nvl(a.leadtime, production.leadtime) leadtime
from production
left join
(
    select item, leadtime
    from production
    where location = 'F01'
) a
    on production.item = a.item
where location <> 'F01';
```